# Crear nueva columna en evento basada en query

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear una columna nueva cada día 28 de cada mes, el problema es que quiero que tenga un nombre en específico basado en una consulta. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `evento_mes`
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2016-11-28 01:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Crea nueva tabla'
    DO 
    BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE `table`
      ADD COLUMN SELECT CONCAT('_',MONTH(NOW()) + 3,'_',YEAR(NOW())+1) 
      VARCHAR(70) 
      NULL DEFAULT NULL;
    END
```

¿Es posible hacer lo que estoy planteando?

Comment: este diseño es una mala idea. Deberías tener una tabla donde cada evento nuevo fuera una **fila**, no una columna

Comment: El problema es que cada fila es un empleado con un dato que se genera mensualmente, pero para no estar aquí todo el día pegado, que se genere sola :)

Comment: No hay problema en que se inserte una fila automáticamente, pero cambiar la estructura de una tabla en forma automática significa que deberías cambiar prácticamente todas las consultas que se hacen sobre esa tabla cada vez. No tiene sentido

Comment: no @AlbertoSiurob, con un buen diseño de bd no debes tener ningun problema... fijate q necesitas otra tabla que diga codigo de emp, mes, dato

Comment: La tengo, tengo una tabla llamada empleados y esta que tengo se llama bono, como el bono es mensual, estoy metiendo a todos mis empleados en mi tabla bono y estoy creando una columna _11_2016 que corresponde al nivel de bono en noviembre, después _12_2016 al nivel de bono de diciembre, pero necesito hacerlo dinámico. ¿Qué me recomiendan?

Comment: Por supuesto que simplemente tu tabla `bono` debería tener una columna que se llame `Periodo` o similar, que tenga el mes del bono (`201611` por ejemplo)

Comment: si, Periodo = _11_2016 osea con otro nombre pero lo tiene. Mi pregunta es, Como por medio de un evento ir creando columnas como: _12_2016, _1_2017 etc.

Comment: No entendiste correctamente. Me refiero a tener una sola columna llamada `Periodo`, y cada **fila** de esa tabla tenga un valor que diga a qué período corresponder

Comment: Como @Lamak te recomendó, es mejor hacerlo con filas. Por ejemplo, cómo podés saber cuál es la última columna? No podés usar ninguna de las funciones de agregación de SQL (min, max, etc) con el diseño que querés implementar. Si los datos queres verlos en columnas, podés hacerlo a través de una consulta, aunque los datos estén en filas.